# Git status shows untracked file on a higher level?

Tags: git

I just cloned a git repository from my server to my local machine. I wanted to see if everything was ok so I made a git status and my suprise is that folders in a level higher than my git repository appear as untracked, "../joomla/", does this make any sense to you?

Comment: Are you sure you're not in a subdirectory of the git repo?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

( This is a guess since you haven't given a lot of detail. But this is a possible scenario):

You had a repo and you cloned it. You ran `git clone url/to/repo.git` from your directory say `/home/repos/my`

Now after the clone, you try `git status` and shows untracked files from `/home/repos`.

So how is this possible?

1) You must have had a `.git` folder ( probably an artifact of previous failed clone, etc) in `/home/repos` ( or even `/home`  etc.)

2) Since you did `git clone url/to/repo.git`, git would have created a folder repo at `/home/repos/my/repo`. But you did the `git status` from `/home/repos/my`. So git goes to parent folders looking for `.git` and found it ( as per 1) and hence shows untracked files.

So see if 2) is your case. Try changing directory to the folder that git has created. Usually you should do a clone as `git clone url/to/repo.git .` ( `.` at end) if you are already in the folder where you want the repo to be.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually it. I didnt realise there was another repo.